# Multiple comparisons of groups with emmeans of a clm: Error in UseMethod("vcoc"): no applicable methos for 'vcov' applied to an object of class "clm"

Tags: r, statistics, emmeans, lsmeans

I'm trying to make a post-hoc tests with emmean/lsmeans for multiple comparisons of groups. In fact, I'm trying to recreate an example found here: https://rcompanion.org/handbook/G_11.html.

Thus, I have a model which looks like this:

```
library(ordinal)

model = clm(Likert.f ~ Instructor + Question + Instructor:Question,
            data = Data,
            threshold="symmetric")


library(car)

library(RVAideMemoire)

Anova(model,
      type = "II")
```

Then I'm trying to explore the group separation for the interaction effect:

```
library(lsmeans)

marginal = lsmeans(model,
                      pairwise ~ Instructor + Question,
                      adjust="tukey")        ### Tukey-adjusted comparisons

marginal

cld(marginal,
    alpha   = 0.05,
    Letters = letters,      ### Use lower-case letters for .group
    adjust  = "tukey")       ### Tukey-adjusted comparisons
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("vcoc"): no applicable methos for 'vcov' applied to an object of class "clm"
```

I also tried the same with emmeans, but with the same error.

Can someone guide me what is wrong? :)

Comment: I can't reproduce with **emmeans** 1.4.5.  What version are you using?  Note in current versions of emmeans the `CLD()` function is deprecated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried it on a different computer and it works, as you said! (Also with emmeans 1.4.5). Embarrasing :D Do you have any idea what to use instead of cld? :)

Comment: The documentation for `CLD()` lists some ideas under the "Deprecated" section (scroll down after running `?CLD`).  The package has switched to reporting p-values for comparisons via `pwpp()` but points to `multcomp::cld()` if you really need compact letter display.

Comment: The generic `cld` function is in another package. Try `multcomp::cld(...)` if you insist on doing this. By consider presenting the comparisons some other way. Compact letter displays are highly misleading because they emphasize non-findings rather than findings. That’s why I deprecated them.

Comment: Thank you so much! :)